# Java 8 Loop : stuck with 2nd for loop initialize variable

Tags: java

//I am looking for loop using streams as follows:

```
int inputArray[] = {4, 6, 5, -10, 8, 1, 2};

    for (int i : inputArray)
            {
                for (int j = i+1; j < inputArray.length; j++)
                {
                    if(inputArray[i]+inputArray[j] == inputNumber)}}
```

// Tried something like but its not working

```
IntStream intStream1 =  Arrays.stream(inputArray);

    intStream1.forEach(i -> {
            IntStream.range(i+1,... ).forEach(j -> {

            });
        });
```

Comment: Your first example doesn't make sense, `inputArray[-9]` isn't going to work (when `i` is `-10` for example).

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to achive. You should at least finish this statement: `if(inputArray[i]+inputArray[j] == inputNumber)`

Comment: It seems that the problem statement should be:  Find any two numbers in an array which sum to a given value.  OP is trying to create all pairs; first by nested loops (but got that wrong), and then by its streams equivalent

Comment: what are you trying to do if you and explain what you want to do in words, it could easy to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the streams answer you are asking for (finding out if any two numbers in an array sum to a given value)

```
int inputArray[] = {4, 6, 5, -10, 8, 1, 2};
int inputNumber = -8;

IntStream.range(0, inputArray.length-1).forEach(i -> IntStream.range(i+1, inputArray.length)
    .forEach(j -> {
        if (inputArray[i]+inputArray[j] == inputNumber) 
            System.out.println("Found "+inputNumber+"; a["+i+"]="+inputArray[i]+" a["+j+"]="+inputArray[j]);
        }));;
```

Which produces the result:

```
Found -8; a[3]=-10 a[6]=2
```

Comment: his problem statement is not clear, but since he has i+1 inside the second loop, the first loop would be IntStream.range(0, inputArray.length -1) ?

Comment: It is very clear that the OP wants to add all pairs.  This is typical algorithm question.

Answer (score 2):

in your expression you iterate through the values of the array, so for

```
for (int i: inputArray)
```

values of **i** will be: `4, 6, 5, -10, 8, 1, 2` sequentially.

Judging by the style of your code, you need

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
```

or similar.

Same story with streams. If you create a primitive stream out of an array of integers, `foreach` would iterate over its values, not indexes. So, you would need to account for indexes yourself. Here is a possible implementation.

```
private static int i = 0, j= 0;
IntStream iStream = Arrays.stream(inputArray);

iStream.forEachOrdered(ival -> {
    j = i+1;
    if (j < inputArray.length) {
        IntStream jStream = Arrays.stream(inputArray, j, inputArray.length);      
        jStream.forEachOrdered(jval -> {
            System.out.println(i + "+" + j + ": " + (ival  + jval));
            j++;
        });
    }
    i++;
});
```

I believe that the above would explain the main idea with streams.

you can also use `IntStram.range()` to iterate across indexes themselves, or use other possible streaming solutions. Please see other answers in this thread as well.

Comment: Op is asking for streams answer

Comment: @IanMc thanks, i added some info to my answer as well.